# Any "hack" to make same CSS button act as a toggle and open 2 different urls in iframe?

Tags: css, toggle

I want to have a toggle button that has two states (on / off colors for example) and depending on each state, I want it to open different URL in an iframe (that will later be hidden), urls like `?cmd=turn_on`, `?cmd=turn_off`.

Can this be done **without JavaScript** ?
By CSS maybe, or by link states (like `a.active{}`) ?

I am thinking it might work to have both buttons defined and hide clicked one and show the other ?! Not sure how to do that by CSS.

Basically I want it to act as a replacement for `xml http request` and I am thinking only way is to make it open the URLs in an iframe.

In another try (**not** below code) the buttons toggle properly with html `checkbox` then css like `input:checked{}` but I cannot wrap that checkbox with an `a` link tag, it would not act as toggle/checkbox anymore.

I think it can be done with some CSS Voodoo:)

```css
a.my_button:link{
    color:#7A1473;
}
a.my_button:visited{
    color:#7A1473;
}
a.my_button:active{
    color:#FFCC00;
}
```

```html
<iframe name="my_iframe"></iframe>

<p>
<a class="my_button" href="/?cmd=turn_on" target="my_iframe">turn on</a> | 
<a class="my_button" href="/?cmd=turn_off" target="my_iframe">turn off</a>
</p>
```

Comment: Why without JS? CSS  by itself can't easily trigger changes in unrelated elements.

Comment: I needed it to work even with js disabled in browser. With JS enabled, I can easily do it.

Comment: In general you should not expect any dynamic actions to work with JS disabled.

Comment: What web site these days works with js disabled?  Is this a school project?

Comment: "What web site these days works with js disabled?" — All the good ones. :p

Comment: If your toggle has two states, what is its initial state?

Comment: @Kosh eider one of the two, like a button with state on/off , it can load in eider state, depending on saved state.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, no you can't achieve that without using javascript because css alone doesn't have the capability to dynamically change the href of an iframe, but you can do what you want in another way by showing that ifram and some styling so it won't look like an ifram and puts your buttons in each page (`/turn_on.html` and `/turn_off.html`), something like this :

#### turn_on.html

```
<style>
    /* some style */
</style>
<p>
    <a class="my_button" href="/turn_off.html">turn off</a>
</p>
```

#### turn_off.html

```
<style>
    /* some style */
</style>
<p>
    <a class="my_button" href="/turn_on.html">turn on</a>
</p>
```

#### index.html

```
<style>
    iframe {
        border: none;
    }
</style>
<iframe name="/turn_off.html"></iframe>
```

### Note: This is not a good practice so i highly recommend that you use javascript in a proper way instead but you can help yourself with this for the moment.

Comment: If I understood correctly, you proposed to display the on/off buttons inside one iframe and make it open/display different url on each click ? I thought of that but in my case it would not work becuase I need to display many switches on same page and loading an iframe by default for each button would cause too many requests.